# nested functions returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi I want to get the result of this function at once inside the items variable, but when I try to return items I get undefined value , can someone explain why and fix it please?

```js
let arr= [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],['a','b','c','d']];
let colp = [0,1,3];

 function selCol(arr,colp) {
     let items = [];
    return colp.forEach((element) => {
      return  arr.map((row) => {

      items.push(row[element]);

      return items;

      });
       
    });

  }
```

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything.  `map()` does.  So `return colp.forEach((element) => {` will always return nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can return `items`, and in that case `map` is not necessary

```
function selCol(arr, colp) {
    let items = [];
    colp.forEach((element) => {
        arr.forEach((row) => {
            items.push(row[element]);
            return items;
        });

    });
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about the 'forEach'. forEach method returns undefined, if you want to return a value either map it or if you want to items in its mutated version, return it directly as such;

```js
function selCol(arr, colp) {
  let items = [];
  colp.forEach((element) => {
    return arr.map((row) => {
      items.push(row[element]);

      return items;
    });
  });
  return items;
}
```